# Django Rest Framework SQL Query CORS

Tags: reactjs, django, iis, django-rest-framework, cors

I am building a tool where users can enter certain parameters and when they hit submit, it will query a mssql database and return some data. The data is passed through Django Rest Framework into a React frontend. The database is massive, so some queries might take several minutes to return.

The issue I'm having is that for queries that take a long time, in the Network tab the status show CORS error: MissingAllowOriginHeader. The data returns fine for shorter queries, for longer queries after 30-45 seconds of loading I will get the CORS error. Also, note that this only occurs on a production IIS server, and works fine on my local server.

I have tried the following in my settings.py already

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = True
```

How I'm getting the data from the sql server

```
class SearchView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kw):
        with connections["mssql"].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql_str)
            all = cursor.fetchall()
```

How I'm making the request from React

```
      axios
        .post(process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH, holder, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "JWT " + sessionStorage.getItem("refresh"),
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this solution below:

1.Go to your site's Handler Mappings.

2.Scroll down to "OPTIONSVerbHandler".

3.Change the 'ProtocolSupportModule' to 'IsapiHandler'.

4.Set the executable: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll.

5.Add this to your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```